# Android onCreateMenuOptions dynamically

Tags: android

I got this image from google and it fits of what I want to show to you. I just want to get the results that are BLUE and I want to do that by code (and not by xml files).

[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Add").setIcon(R.drawable.myicon);
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that the value "Add" appears inside the Orange arrow in the image, and I want to display outside with a image (at left side).

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`setShowAsAction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsAction%28int%29) on your MenuItem. As per the [Menus guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu), the items that are show in the action bar are called action items. The menu you pointed out in orange is the action overflow menu.

The documentation lists the various flags you can pass in. The one you are looking for is `SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS`.

If you use `SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM`, the menu items that don't fit in the ActionBar will automatically be moved to the overflow menu. If you use `SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER`, they will always be in the overflow menu.

If you are supporting an API version less than 11 (3.0), make sure that you wrap `setShowAsAction()` in an API version check.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But how can I achieve have Image and Text?
`MenuItem SaveMenu = menu.add(Menu.NONE , Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Save");
SaveMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.pin_location);
  SaveMenu.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);`
With this, I don't get nor image nor text. The text appears inside the "settings menu" by default.

Comment: The documentation states that you need to OR another flag with the `SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT` flag. Thus your code should be something like `SaveMenu.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);`

Answer (score 0):

those are actionbar items

1.create icons and copy in drawable folder
2.in MENU folder create xml file and add this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/newrss_actionbar"
    android:icon="@drawable/content_new"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/abc"/>
```

3.in activity file use it like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.newrss_actionbar:
            //do your work
            return true;
}
```